# Nginx Error ("http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abc)

Tags: nginx

I am geeting below error while starting Nginx service

"http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abc:1

Here is my abc config

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/lua.log debug;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
  upstream kibana {
    server server1:30001;
    server server2:30001;
    keepalive 15;
  }
  server {
    listen 8882;
    location / {
        ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/ELK-Stack.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/ELK-Stack.key;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;
      proxy_pass http://kibana;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
      proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    }
  }
}
```

--> FYI I am creating this file in /etc/nginx/sites-available and linking it to
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled . I am providing a link using following command

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/abc /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abc
```

After the above command I can see a link is been created in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled directory .

Please suggest what I am doing wrong ?

Regards,

Comment: The configuration file for `nginx` is called `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. The files in `sites-enabled` are fragments which are included into it. The `http` section is in the main configuration file - you need to put `server` blocks in the `sites-enabled` files.

Comment: Thanks Richard , so in my sites-enabled I have removed everything and just placed server block as you suggested . Now since servers block had proxy_pass http://kibana so it gives me an error that servers are not defined so I placed upstream kibana block directly in nginx.conf . With this approach I am not getting any error but while hitting nginx IP I got nothing , page says this site cannot be reached. It seems upstream block is not supported by nginx.conf .

Answer (score 2):

The http directive dos not belong there.

In the ngnix.conf you have already the http directive

```
http {
    ..config logs ...
    inclide etc/ngnix/sites-enabled/*;  <--- This Line include your files
    .. more config...
    server {
       (..default server ...)
       location / {
           index 
           root 
       }
    }
}
```

The files in your sites enabled must only contain servers, the http directive is in the principal configuration. 
I would try:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

  upstream kibana {
    server server1:30001;
    server server2:30001;
    keepalive 15;
  }

    error_log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/lua.log debug;

    listen 8882;
    location / {
        basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;
      proxy_pass http://kibana;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
      proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/ELK-Stack.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/ELK-Stack.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Zartch makes sense to me , I tried what you suggested but did not work for me . So I have added include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; in nginx.conf and edit abc file in sites-available as you mentioned above and then again I made a link between avaialble and enabled . Now it says "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abc

Comment: so if I tried removing worker_processes 1; then it says worker_connection cannot define . I removed both now it says ssl_certificate cannot be defined.

Comment: Indeed, ssl* params belongs to server directive, and worker_connections to events (but I'm not sure about that, i configure workers on uwsgi) I corrected in the answer.